# Creating an animated radial gradient in Processing, similar to the Solar Weather App

Tags: processing

I'm trying to create a radial gradient in Processing, and animate the gradient to give it a slow breathing effect. The gradient needs to oscillate between two color sets - an effect seen in Solar, the iOS weather app.

I found the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920768/creating-an-animated-gradient-background-similar-to-the-solar-weather-applicatio) asked for xCode, but I'd like to get some pointers for Processing.

Here's an image that explains my question better:
[image]

I stumbled on the 'Radial Gradient' [example code](http://processing.org/examples/radialgradient.html), but I'm not quite sure how to proceed with animating the gradient, and creating the hole in the center to form the donut shape.

Any sample code, pointers, suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to access `java.awt.Graphics2D` (also known as Java 2D) and use `RadialGradientPaint`.

Processing's [example code](http://processing.org/examples/radialgradient.html) for drawing a radial gradient is not efficient enough for the effect you are trying to achieve and arguably harder to implement.

Here's a simple example to help you get started, move the mouse up and down to interpolate between the `startColors` and `endColors`. Always refer to the java docs for more help [RadialGradient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html).

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.*;

Graphics2D g2;
Rectangle2D.Double rectangle;

Point2D center;
Point2D focus;
float radius;
float[] dist = { 0.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f };

Color[] gradColors = new Color[dist.length];

Color[] endColors = {
    new Color(254, 189, 75), // yellow
    new Color(255, 98, 43), // red
    new Color(87, 25, 198) // violet
};

Color[] startColors = {
    new Color(232, 185, 71),
    new Color(180, 98, 56),
    new Color(87, 36, 68)
};

void setup() {
  size(300, 600); // make sure NOT to use P2D
  g2 = ((PGraphicsJava2D)g).g2;

  rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
  radius = height;
  center = new Point2D.Float(width/2.0f, height);
  focus = new Point2D.Float(width/2.0f, height);
  updateColors(0);
}

void draw() {
  RadialGradientPaint gradient =
         new RadialGradientPaint(center,
                                 radius, 
                                 focus,
                                 dist, 
                                 gradColors,
                                 RadialGradientPaint.CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE);
  g2.setPaint(gradient);
  g2.fill(rectangle);
}

void mouseMoved() {
  updateColors((float) mouseY / height);
}

void updateColors(double blend) {
  for(int i = 0; i < gradColors.length; i++) {
    gradColors[i] = lerpColor(startColors[i], endColors[i], blend);
  }
}

Color lerpColor(Color color1, Color color2, double blend) {
  double inverseBlend = 1.0 - blend;
  int redPart = (int) (color1.getRed() * blend + color2.getRed() * inverseBlend);
  int greenPart = (int) (color1.getGreen() * blend + color2.getGreen() * inverseBlend);
  int bluePart = (int) (color1.getBlue() * blend + color2.getBlue() * inverseBlend);
  return new Color(redPart, greenPart, bluePart);
}
```