# Animate CAGradientLayer in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am attemping to animate the CAGradientLayer using Swift. For a resource I'm using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920768/creating-an-animated-gradient-background-similar-to-the-solar-weather-applicatio)

Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var gradient : CAGradientLayer?;

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    self.gradient?.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.gradient?.colors = [ UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, atIndex: 0)

    animateLayer()
  }

  func animateLayer(){

    var fromColors = self.gradient?.colors
    var toColors: [AnyObject] = [ UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]

    var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")

    animation.fromValue = fromColors
    animation.toValue = toColors
    animation.duration = 3.00
    animation.removedOnCompletion = true
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.delegate = self

    self.gradient?.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"animateGradient")
  }
}
```

I've attempted this in Objective-C and it works, but I need to use it in Swift and when I run the program it animates but goes back to the previous color at the end, I need it so remain blue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have checked your code and found one mistake here. You forgot to set color of `self.gradient` you are just giving colors to animation thats why animation is working fine and at the end you see its color goes back to `red`.

Write this missing code:

```
var toColors: [AnyObject] = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]
self.gradient.colors = toColors // You missed this line
var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
```

You can also check working code here: [Sample](http://pastie.org/10305903)

**UPDATE: *how do I repeat this gradient transition continuously ?***

So you can use `delegate` of `CAAnimation`. It will let you know once the animation has been finished and then you can set the `fromColors` and `toColors` value and call the `animateLayer()` function again and again. But for this you will have to make few changes in your code.

- Make `fromColors` and `toColors` global.
- Change their value in `animationDidStop` delegate method.
- Call the `animateLayer()` function again.

Here is the `delegate` method body:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {

    self.toColors = self.fromColors;
    self.fromColors = self.gradient?.colors
    animateLayer()
}
```

And you can also check working code here: [Sample](http://pastie.org/10360656)

Comment: how do I repeat this gradient transition continuously ?

Comment: Any idea why the animation begins to flicker/stutter & go crazy once you segue to another view and return back to it?

Comment: @theflarenet Please make sure you are not starting new animation while coming back. Avoid making new instance of this animation OR stop last animation then start new one.

Comment: @TheTiger Excellent work on developing the method of continuously repeating the animation; however, I am having trouble stopping the last animation in order to start a new one in this case. Returning to the segue interferes with the delegate and `animateLayer()`, and `removedOnCompletion` within.

Comment: Just a heads-up for anyone out there, `animationLayer()` will cause the CPU to spike up to 100% if you segue to another view. I'm unsure of how to stop all animations and put the whole initial view to a halt. Hope someone recognizes this; however, this is a nice workaround for a continuous transition.

Comment: @theflarenet I told you! Don't initialize anything again. Just change their values. Make them global and initialize once what you don't need to change. Just change values in that function.

Comment: @TheTiger I understand that I shouldn't initalize anything but what I don't understand is what I should exactly change to make the animation pause/stop--so to speak. `animation.duration = 0`? Also, I noticed that wrapping the `animationDidStop()` contents with a `if (flag)` solves the 100% CPU issue. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Note that the animation object has a `repeatCount` and a `autoreverses` property that handles repetition quite nicely without the need for delegates or timers.

Answer (score 6):

For those in the comments asking about endless animations, here's my stock sample code for an endlessly animated background:-

The full discussion and results [can be seen on my blog](https://appcodelabs.com/make-your-ios-app-pop-animated-gradients)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create the gradient layer
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0, y:0.5)
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
        gradient.locations =  [-0.5, 1.5]

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
        animation.fromValue = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
        animation.toValue = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
        animation.duration = 5.0
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        // add the animation to the gradient
        gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)

        // add the gradient to the view
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not working. It only creates a gradient but no animation.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference... The 100% CPU usage is caused by the animationDidStop function. It restarts the animation while the current animations isn't finished. Please check the finished flag:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished: Bool) {
    if finished {
        self.toColors = self.fromColors;
        self.fromColors = self.gradient?.colors

        animateLayer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've attempted this in Objective-C and it works, but I need to use it
>   in Swift and when I run the program it animates but goes back to the
>   previous color at the end, I need it so remain blue.

You need just :

```
animation.removedOnCompletion = false // not true like in your code
```

Comment: No recommended, if you change the colors again it wont start from the current color